# How to make a custom callback_data in pyTelegramBotApi?

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I have an inline keyboard in my message, so I want to transmit some data with callback, like in this example (obv, that's not working, cause `callback_data` must be a string)

```py
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('DO IT!', callback_data={'tp':'adm', 'com':'addf', 'con':info})
```

I want my callback handler to handle some data, but I don't really know how to write it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make string from your data despite of type you have. For python `dict` you can use `json` library:

```py
import json
data = {'tp':'adm', 'com':'addf', 'con':info}
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('DO IT!', callback_data=json.dumps(data))
```

But FYI it supports max length of only 64 characters ([source](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton)). So either you'll fit it or find the way how to compress your data.